# Implement SIP server for android 4.0

Tags: android, sip

I want to implement SIP server and SIP client programs for android 4.0. In android samples already provides the "SIPdemo" SIP client program. It's use the android.net.sip package.

Can I use the android.net.sip package for implement the SIP server? 
Is there any sample SIP server programs for android?

Answer (score 4):

I think it is possible , I find this product in market usipserver it s free .
 So it s possible to make you own sip server in Android 
but I don't think  with just  android.sip , you must writing all code for the server use directly native code ( socket etc )

Answer (score 2):

No. If you want a sip server, you can use [Asterisk](http://www.asterisk.org/). Install and run it on a server machine and register the SipDemo into it.

Comment: FreeSWITCH would probably be easier to install/configure.

Answer (score 1):

I think http://www.linphone.org might be what you're looking for.

The android sip api requires a server I think.